# Check if an array exists in a HashSet<int[]>

Tags: java, arrays, collections, contains, hashset

How do I check if an array exists in a `HashSet`?

For example:

```java
int[] a = new int[]{0, 0};

HashSet<int[]> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(a);
```

Then:

```java
int[] b = new int[]{0, 0};

set.contains(b); // ===> true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Using arrays

```
    int[] a = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    HashSet<int[]> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(a);

    int[] b = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    
    boolean contains = set.stream().anyMatch(c -> Arrays.equals(c, b));
    
    System.out.println("Contains? " + contains);
```

Output:

> Contains? true

It doesn’t exploit the fast look up of a `HashSet` though. As noted in the comments, this is not possible because `equals` and `hashCode` for arrays doesn’t consider arrays containing the same numbers in the same order equal. An array is only considered equal to itself. We therefore need a linear search through the set to find the array containing the same numbers if there is one. I am using a stream pipeline for that. You may alternatively use a loop.

### Faster: using lists

To exploit the fast lookup in a `HashSet` you may use lists instead of arrays:

```
    List<Integer> a = List.of(0, 0);
    HashSet<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(a);

    List<Integer> b = List.of(0, 0);
    
    System.out.println("Contains? " + set.contains(b));
```

> Contains? true

The `List<Integer>` approach has a space penalty, though, since it is storing `Integer` objects rather than `int` primitives, which generally takes up more space.

### Both space and time efficient: develop a custom class

If the above still isn’t efficient enough — which it is for the vast majority of purposes — you may use your own class for the numbers:

```
public class IntArray {

    int[] elements;
    
    public IntArray(int... elements) {
        // Make a defensive copy to shield from subsequent modifications of the original array
        this.elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(elements);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        IntArray other = (IntArray) obj;
        return Arrays.equals(elements, other.elements);
    }

}
```

This will allow:

```
    IntArray a = new IntArray(0, 0);
    HashSet<IntArray> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(a);

    IntArray b = new IntArray(0, 0);
    
    System.out.println("Contains? " + set.contains(b));
```

> Contains? true

Now we have the space efficiency of the original `int` array approach, nearly, and the time efficiency of the `hashCode()`.

### More options (thanks, fluffy)

As fluffy notes in the comments, there are still more options, and you may want to research some on your own. I am quoting the comments here:

> Also, there can be two key-based solutions if I'm not wrong: something
> like
>
> ```
> public final class IntArrayKey {
>     private final int[];
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> (suffers from possible array mutation or defensive array cloning), or
> something like
>
> ```
> public final class Key<T> {
>     private final Predicate<T> equals;
>     private final IntSupplier hashCode;
>     public static Key<int[]> of(final int[] array) {
>         return new Key<>(that -> Arrays.equals(array, that), () -> Arrays.hashCode(array));
>     }
> ```
>
> to keep it generic.
>
> And probably one more solution I can think of is using
> [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) or
> [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html) instead of
> `List<Integer>` (e.g.
> [`IntList`](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntList.html)
> that overrides `equals` and `hashCode` properly). Not sure it worth
> adding all possible solutions (perhaps there are more?) now. :)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it's worth adding a custom key class solution, since creating such a key class instance can be cheaper in terms of memory use (especially for big primitive arrays that do not necessarily use ints from the `Integer` cache + it would work for other "exotic" cases like `double[]` or `char[]`), and faster (especially for big hash-oriented collections, where using linear search is a performance killer).

Comment: Good point, @fluffy, thanks. You may add that in your own answer if you like, or I may add it in mine. For now I have mentioned the space penalty, inspired from your comment.

Comment: Yes, please add it if you want: a single answer that covers most/all cases is better (in my opinion). Also, there can be two key-based solutions if I'm not wrong: something like `public final class IntArrayKey{ private final int[]; ... }` (suffers from possible array mutation or defensive array cloning), or something like `public final class Key<T> { private final Predicate<T> equals; private final IntSupplier hashCode; public static Key<int[]> of(final int[] array) { return new Key<>(that -> Arrays.equals(array, that), () -> Arrays.hashCode(array)); }` to keep it generic.

Comment: And probably one more solution I can think of is using [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) or [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html) instead of `List<Integer>` (e.g. [`IntList`](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntList.html) that overrides `equals` and `hashCode` properly). Not sure it worth adding all possible solutions (perhaps there are more?) now. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead of [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) with a comparator that compares the *contents* of two arrays instead of the *hash codes* of two array objects. Then you can use [`TreeSet.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method as follows:

```java
int[] a = {0, 0};
int[] b = {0, 0};
int[] c = {0, 0};

HashSet<int[]> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
TreeSet<int[]> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare);

hashSet.addAll(List.of(a, b, c));
treeSet.addAll(List.of(a, b));

System.out.println(hashSet.size()); // 3
System.out.println(treeSet.size()); // 1

System.out.println(treeSet.contains(a)); // true
System.out.println(treeSet.contains(b)); // true
System.out.println(treeSet.contains(c)); // true
```